# Error al comprobar una expresión regular en JS

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Tengo una función en JavaScript que toma un valor por ID, comprueba si existe y si cumple cierta expresión regular:

```
function consultarTelefono(){
    var telf = new RegExp("[6-9]{1}\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}");   //El primer dígito debe ser 6,7,8,9 seguido de dos más. Puede contener un espacio (o no) y tres dígitos más y repetimos.
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
    if(document.getElementById("telefono").value.length && !telf.test(document.getElementById("telefono").value)){
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
        alert("El teléfono no sigue el formato adecuado. Debe tener 9 números y comenzar por 6, 7, 8 o 9");
        return;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Pero al pasarle un teléfono al formulario cualquier número hace saltar el mensaje de error. Mi intención es que el campo Telefono pueda estar en blanco pero si contiene algún número que este cumpla la expresión regular: que sea un número de 9 cifras, que pueda empezar por 6,7,8 o 9 y que contenga 8 dígitos más tal que 986754321 o 986 754 321.

No consigo ver por qué falla, alguna idea?

Anexo HTML:

```js
function consultarTelefono(){
    var telf = new RegExp("[6-9]{1}\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}");   //El primer dígito debe ser 6,7,8,9 seguido de dos más. Puede contener un espacio (o no) y tres dígitos más y repetimos.
    //document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
    if(document.getElementById("telefono").value.length && !telf.test(document.getElementById("telefono").value)){
        //document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
        alert("El teléfono no sigue el formato adecuado. Debe tener 9 números y comenzar por 6, 7, 8 o 9");
        return;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
            <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__telefono__email">
                <p class="Descripciones">Introduzca los datos de contacto</p>
                <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                    <label class="formulario__label">Teléfono:</label>  <!--El formato lo comprobamos mediante JS-->
                    <input type="text" class="formulario__input" name="ctlph" id="telefono" placeholder="Número de teléfono" title="El número de teléfono debe estar formado 9 nñumeros y comenzar por 6, 7, 8 o 9. Ej: 987654321" onchange="consultarTelefono()">
                    
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <label class="formulario__label">e-mail:</label>   <!--El formato se comprueba solo al ser de tipo email-->
                    <input type="email" class="formulario__input" name="cemail" id="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" title="El correo debe ser un correo válido. Ej: contacto@anxo.com">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu expresión regular se ve bien, aunque el {1} es innecesario. El problema es el formato:

```js
const regex = /[6-9]{1}\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}/;
const regex2 = new RegExp("[6-9]{1}\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}");

console.log(regex.test('666 777 888'));
console.log(regex.test('666777888'));

console.log(regex2.test('666 777 888'));
console.log(regex2.test('666777888'));
```

¿Qué está pasando?

El carácter \ sirve para indicar carácter especial en una expresión regular, pero también sirve para indicar un carácter especial en un *string*. Esto hace que si usas un *string* para declarar una expresión regular, tengas que *escaparlo*:

```
"[6-9]\\d{2}(\\s?\\d{3}){2}" //doble \
```

La otra opción es usar el formato que ves en mi ejemplo, poniendo la expresión regular entre dos `/`:

```
const regex = /[6-9]\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}/;
```

Como detalle final, limitar los dígitos con los caracteres especiales para indicar inicio y fin, como ha comentado @D4RIO:

```
const regex = /^[6-9]\d{2}(\s?\d{3}){2}$/;
```

Comment: Genial, la expresión ahora me funciona con una salvedad, si en el teléfono introduzco más de 9 números también me lo da por false, hay alguna manera de limitar la expresión a exactamente 9 dígitos?

Comment: Inicialo con ^ y terminalo con $. Así le decís que no solo debe existir match de la RE sino que toda la cadena, de principio a fin, debe ser un match.